# Appending user input to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a little problem. I need to write a function in pyhton that appends user input in a list. But it should append only numbers. If user inputs numbers it should return list with those numbers and if user inputs something else it should return list without changes. 
By numbers I mean that it must work with int and with float.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: I tried using if num.isdigit() == True: l.append(num) but that works only with integers

Comment: I don't see any code in your question at all. I see a list of requirements. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
def append_num(list, add_this):
         if type(add_this) == int or type(add_this) == float:
            list.append(add_this)
```

You seem to have been trying to use the isdigit() method, but that only tells you if a string is made up of digits. You should first ensure that the input from users can ever consist of floats and ints or if it's always strings, in which case the solution will be different.